# Setting subtitle on ActionBar compat

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I have a project with ActionBar, where dynamically I change the subtitle. But now I must extend app's compatibility, so I've added support v7 to have ActionBar Compat.

For this, I've done:

- Import `android-support-v7-appcompat` and add as library to my project
- Set Aplication theme as: `Theme.AppCompat`
- Extend Activities to `ActionBarActivity`

But still have some methods that I use to set the Subtitle, that tells me that they require API level 11, and my current min is 7.

Theses are the methods:

```
private final void setStatus(CharSequence subTitle) {
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();  //getActionBar() throws it
    actionBar.setSubtitle(subTitle);  //setSubtitle() throws it
```

Comment: please do at least **some** research before posting, this is all over the documentation [here] (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html), [here] (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) or [here] (http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are still using methods that are not compatible with older versions of Android. Try using [getSupportActionBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#getSupportActionBar%28%29) instead of getActionBar.

You should of course check that your are importing the correct ActionBar version, and you will get access to that method, as per [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setSubtitle%28int%29).

Good luck ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the `Actionbar` from the SupportLib at the moment.

Change `getActionBar()` to `getSupportActionBar()`.

Another point, do not forget to set the correct display options on your `Actionbar` like so:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
```

Comment: Where do I have to define `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);`? Inside the function, just before getSupportActionBar()?

Comment: Preferably, in your onCreate function